# Fixing delay and blurred together notes with Kontakt horns and strings

Tags: software, vst, ableton

My current setup for composing is Ableton Live 9 and Kontakt 5. I am facing a problem with Session Strings and Symphony Brass with delayed notes and blurred together notes. The delayed notes are not an issue as I can just add a negative track delay, but the overlapping blurred notes are an issue. The actual MIDI that the instrument is using does not have overlapping notes yet on faster phrases all of the notes sustain and blur together. Here are two audio examples, the first is using a piano to show what it should sound like and the second is using a trumpet both with piano accompaniment to keep time:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib1m70r0z1lmtui/Piano.wav?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6168sto5akgelbz/Trumpet.wav?dl=0

I am using legato patches in Kontakt and I've tried raising the audio buffer in case it was due to lack of processing power. I'm not sure how I can fix this (or if I am going about it completely wrong). Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Are you quantizing a human performance? If so that could be the cause.

Comment: The MIDI itself is an export from Sibelius so it wasn't actually played in by anyone. This makes it completely quantised with all of the notes lasting until the next. Could that cause problems?